# How do I use a combo box value in query criteria, or show all results if blank?

Tags: ms-access

Currently, I'm trying to reference a combo box value in a query's criteria. Usually, I use a Like statement. However, in this instance, I'm trying to filter by some strings that aren't unique.

[image]

If I were to try to filter by MW, for instance, it would show MW, MWF, MWRF.

I've tried `Nz([forms]![frmReschedWorkload]![FilterFactCal],'Is Not Null')`. While that does filter correctly if there's a value in the combo box, it's not showing any results if the text box is blank.

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to anyone coming in the future, I was able to solve with putting this into the criteria:

```
IIf(IsNull([forms]![frmReschedWorkload]![FilterFactCal]),[tblOrders].[FactoryCalendar],[forms]![frmReschedWorkload]![FilterFactCal])
```